# Cannot run Java Web Start JNLP

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, jnlp

I've got a peculiar problem of java. I'm using Windows 7 64bit version and got JDK 1.7 64bit and 32 bit, but the thing is, I'm unable to open the JNLP files downloaded (for eg. from Oracle Tutorials) Is this problem due to the conflict of two different architectures of Java or there is any other reason behind it? If I install any one of the JRE (either 64bit or 32 bit), it is working fine and I can run them. But if I uninstall 64bit, my application won't run, if I remove 32bit, I'm unable to view java content on the web. So, I want to have both of them to be present. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: if you have installed jdk 1.7 then you should not have any problems, as it comes with javaws. My question is why you need 64 and 32 bit both installed on your system ? Is there any specific application that is running on 32 bit jre ? which application is not running for you with 64 bit ?

Comment: My web-browser can't detect 64 bit JRE. I cannot get verified of having Java from the java website, though I have JRE 64bit installed.

Comment: which web browser are you using ? have you set Java path ?

Comment: @Rajesh What you describe typically happens when you use Internet Explorer 32 bits - Windows 7 has both IE 32bits and IE 64bits, make sure you use the right version (i.e. the version corresponding to the JRE you have installed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But I use Opera. It is also 32 bit, so I'm not able to view the Java Content. My problem is mainly due to the conflict between two versions, x64 and x86. If both are present, everything is working fine except JNLP Java Web Start, If I remove anyone, JNLP is working but, version specific apps donot run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your Java JRE. I suggest you to update the x86 Java because, the cause, why I expect is a version conflict for the both of them.

Comment: It worked! Thanks alot. I updated the JRE to Update 9 and have all components running incl JNLP